# How to determine if two vectors form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ be a linear transformation such that $T (1,1)=(9,2)$ and $T(2,-3)=(4,-1)$.
>
> A) Determine if the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(2,-3)$ form a basis.
> B) Calculate $T(x,y)$.

I need help with these, please I'm stuck, don't even know how to start them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$\{(1,1),(2,-3)\}$ is a basis if and only if the vectors are linearly independent (note that the vector space is two-dimensional). Are they linearly independent?

To compute $T(x,y)$ use that $$(1,0)=\frac 35(1,1)+\frac 15(2,-3),$$ $$(0,1)=\frac 25(1,1)-\frac 15(2,-3)$$ and $$(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1).$$

Answer (score 2):

You can't scalair multiply $(1,1)$ to get $(2, -3)$, so the vectors are linear independent. So the span of these vectors are a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ (dimension is also ok).

Answer (score 1):

If two vectors $x_1,x_2$ are linearly dependent, the either
$x_1 = \lambda x_2$ or $x_2=\lambda x_1$ for some $\lambda$, in other words
they lie on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

a) hint: Check linear independence.
b) Write any vector (x,y) as linear combination of basis you have and use the property of linear operator.

Comment: Maybe that's my main doubt. Do I have to ignore that the two vectors are "related" to a linear transformation and proceed just checking if they are Independent and span the R^2 space ??